# Cast Deserialised Object to Another Type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm calling an API that returns a standard response structure for all actions. I deserialise the response using Newtonsoft.Json and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>`

```
 public class Response
 {
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public object Result { get; set; }

    public DateTime ResponseDateTime { get; set; }
 }
```

The Result object changes depending on the request action that has been requested and if there was an error or not (Code + Message describe errors). I know the structure of the Result objects and have created classes for each Result I require.

How do i go about casting the Result object to a typed variable such as a `Detail[]`? I know i can serialize the Result object and deserialise it again but surely there is a more elegant solution.

```
 public class Detail
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string DetailOne { get; set; }

    public string DetailTwo { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: How do you identify the kind of object `Result` should be?

Comment: What is `Result.GetType()`?

Comment: It would be super if you could post actual JSON code that you need to deserialize?

Comment: Result.GetType() for this request is a JArray, Will that change if the Result is not an array type?

Comment: @Paperwaste: Yes, it would be a `JObject` or just a `JValue` for non-arrays.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Can i suggest you contribute something constructive. Eg, Why is the approach nonsense? What would you change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always know what kind of `Result` you'll get, I'd suggest making `Response` generic:

```
public class Response<TResult>
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public T Result { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResponseDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can just deserialize to a `Response<Detail[]>` and Json.NET should handle everything fine.

This is assuming that if there's an error, you won't end up with a `Result` that could be problematic. Alternatively, you could still deserialize to a `Response` class, but with a `JToken` property type:

```
public class Response
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public JToken Result { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResponseDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then use:

```
Response response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
if (response.Code == 200) // Or whatever
{
    Detail[] details = response.Result.ToObject<Detail[]>();
}
```

You could potentially wrap that into a generic method. I'd at least *try* the generic response class first though.

Comment: I really like the generic response class approach. I'll try to make it work with that. I'll have to check exactly what happens to the Result if there is an error. I don't think i will get a different Response object type more likely it will just be null.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your object model to this:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public T Result { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResponseDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DetailOne { get; set; }
    public string DetailTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var original = new Response<Detail>()
{
    Code = 42,
    Message = "OK",
    Result = new Detail()
    {
        Id = 1701,
        DetailOne = "Don't",
        DetailTwo = "Panic",
    },
    ResponseDateTime = DateTime.Now,
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(original, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>>(json);

if (response.Code == 42)
{
    Detail detail = response.Result.ToObject<Detail>();

    /* Do something with `Detail`. */
}
```

That seems a fairly nice way to get to the underlying `Detail` object.

The key technique is to serialize a `Response<Detail>` and deserialize as a `Response<JToken>`. Simple.

Of course, if you really wanted to create a `Response<Detail>` instance you could make a fairly straightforward way of converting from `Response<JToken>` to `Response<Detail>` by doing a straight field-to-field mapping.

---

Here is the `Response<Detail[]>` version of the code:

```
var original = new Response<Detail[]>()
{
    Code = 42,
    Message = "OK",
    Result = new Detail[]
    {
        new Detail()
        {
            Id = 1701,
            DetailOne = "Don't",
            DetailTwo = "Panic",
        },
        new Detail()
        {
            Id = 360,
            DetailOne = "Microsoft",
            DetailTwo = "Xbox",
        }
    },
    ResponseDateTime = DateTime.Now,
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(original, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>>(json);

if (response.Code == 42)
{
    Detail[] detail = response.Result.ToObject<Detail[]>();

    /* Do something with `Detail[]`. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the code does not determine the type of Result it is used to describe Success/Error. The Expected Result type changes depending on the what Action I call on the API.

Comment: @Paperwaste - The same can be said about the accepted answer. Or am I wrong? Can you explain how the expected result changes? I didn't see that in your question.